# Playing videos one after another in html5

Tags: javascript, html, video

I am playing videos one after another in following code,

```
<html>
<body>
    <video src="videos/video1.mp4" id="myVideo" autoplay>
        video not supported
    </video>
</body>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        var count=1;
    var player=document.getElementById('myVideo');
    player.addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);

    function myHandler(e) {
        if(!e) 
        { e = window.event; }
        count++;
        player.src="videos/video"+count+".mp4";
        }
</script>
```

Now, my question is, There are many video files having different name (in remote directory) which is on server and 
I don't know name of all files. So how to make their queue and play one after another using JavaScript??

Comment: are http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20945886/video-queue-in-html5  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20942900/playing-videos-one-after-another-in-html5  **duplications**?

Answer (score 12):

This work for me :)

```
<video width="256" height="192"  id="myVideo" controls autoplay>
    <source src="video/video1.mp4" id="mp4Source" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

<script type='text/javascript'>
   var count=1;
   var player=document.getElementById('myVideo');
   var mp4Vid = document.getElementById('mp4Source');
   player.addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);

   function myHandler(e)
   {

      if(!e) 
      {
         e = window.event; 
      }
      count++;
      $(mp4Vid).attr('src', "video/video"+count+".mp4");
      player.load();
      player.play();
   }

</script>
```

Comment: This works very nicely. Just that I have to modify a little because I am using Vue.js

Comment: not sure why you used JQuery on just that one line: $(mp4Vid).attr('src', "video/video"+count+".mp4"); can be mp4Vid.setAttribute("src","video/video"+count+".mp4");

Comment: Problem here, at least in react. Is the media is redownloaded. Have yet to find a solution that doesn't involve creating individual video tags

Answer (score 0):

Your variables are inconsistent:

change

```
videoplayer.src=nextvid;
```

to

```
videoPlayer.src = nextvid;
```

also, according to the solution that you linked, it appears that the user fixed it by binding it via javascript instead of using the `onended` attribute. Have you tried that?

```
videoPlayer.onended(function(e) {
 run();
};
```

Comment: Ya i tried that. Even It was not working and I did corrections still it is not working..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but i did something similar with pictures. Try using an if statement to determine if the video is done playing or a button is pressed and then change the src of the video to the next one in an array ex:
$("#my_videos").attr("src",videos[turn]);

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to get the list of video files as a response from the server.
2. Store the response in an Array say "playlist".
3. Then change the video src as player.src=playlist[count]. Here "count" is the same counter you are using now.