# How to play adds in html 5 video player while playing the video

Tags: html, html5-video

How to play adds in html 5 video player while playing the video..
using `<video>` tag

Yes I'm not get correct results
Video tag having controls and play and pause, mute and unmute and scr, poster, kind of all features.

Now im looking for this Adds playing

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What kind of Ads? It completely depends on the format of the ad. If the ad is a normal video then the video tag would be correct and you could remove the controls from it. If you use YouTube or an ad provider, then they most-likely require the usage of iframes.

Answer (score 0):

Please attach some images that people can work with, as right now we don't know how much progress you have.

You can try doing it in JavaScript, by having 2 video elements and switching between them based on a timer!

This question has been asked before:
**[How do I put ads in a video player?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67817497/how-do-i-put-ads-in-a-video-player)**